# Sending an email from Create-React-App contact form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a website that I used [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to create. 
I need to make a contact page where the information entered will be sent to a specified email.

After doing some research I discovered this is going to require me to setup some back-end. I am *very* unfamiliar with back-end programming. I know about nodejs and am somewhat capable of setting up a basic server using that, but I have no clue how to connect it to the react site, or if I even need a node server (just mentioned it because I found [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/)).

What's a good back-end setup I should use? All I need to use it for is sending an input field's value to a specific email.

I'm sorry this is such a noob/vague question, I am just looking for some direction on what to start researching and learning. I don't expect a detailed answer on the purpose and precise operations of a back-end server, just some helpful guidance or somewhere to start learning!

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](http://emailjs.com?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of two options to connect to the back-end to send an email.

1. API: You create an endpoint on your backend (i.e. https://yourdomain.com/api/sendemail). Using expressjs, or some other server side library, you create that endpoint to receive a `POST` request. (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) You then use the front-end (fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to call the endpoint with the data needed in the email and in turn the endpoint calls your send email function with Nodemailer or whatever.
2. Form Submit: The other option is similar to the first in that it sends a `POST` request with the form data to the back-end. This requires that the server send back a new page and your browser will then reload. Where as the first option can be done without a page reload.

Not an expert on this but those are the two options I know of. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! Super helpful resources.